# Premake Script: How to look into parent directory for file

Tags: lua, premake

This is a fairly simple question looking for a fairly simple answer. If I want to create a solution in the parent directory of the premake4.lua file, how do I specify that relative to the premake4.lua file location? This is what I am trying to do

In folder "Test", which is a subdirectory of "Premake Test", there is a file called test.lua located in Test, this file is invoked by the dofile command in premake4.lua, which is in Premake Test. From test.lua I need to create the solution, do not ask why, it is simply a project I am doing to better learn how to use premake, no different from the review exercises at the end of a chapter in a programming book.
Here is test.lua:

```
solution "Premake Directories"
    location "Parent Directory of This File..."
    configurations {"Debug", "Release"}
project "Test"
    kind "StaticLib"
    language "C++"
    files{
        "test.h",
        "test.cpp"

    }
```

So how do i modify the parameter to location so that I can access the parent directory? Thanks!

Comment: Would simply `location "../"` not work?

Comment: Thats what it was I think, could not remember, I will try that now.

Comment: Has this question been answered? If so, you should mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Paths in Premake are always specified relative the currently running script. So that should be:

```
solution "Premake Directories"
   location ".."
   configurations { "Debug", "Release" }
```